# Прошу помочь мне разобраться с наложением текстур на объекты в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, blender

Создаю объект в Blender'e, накладываю текстуры - все шикарно, в нем можно настроить, как надо накладывать текстуру на объект, и проблем с этим не возникает.
[image]
Обратите внимание, как легла текстура на крышу.

---

Потом экспортирую этот объект в Unity3D. Текстуры не экспортируются, и приходится загружать их отдельно, но это полбеды. Я не нашел, как можно настроить расположение текстуры. В итоге получается следущее (**смотрим на крышу**).

[image]

Вместо того, чтобы натянуться равномерно вокруг центра, текстура просто кладется сверху, и ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Comment: Ответ оказался прост - [UV развертка](http://blender3d.com.ua/uv-razvertka-v-blender/).

Comment: Тут можно посмотреть видео урок [Моделирование и текстурирование в Blender для unity 3D](http://programishka.ru/catalog/show_catalog/100/)